# How to render indent trees with QuickGraph in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, graph-drawing, quickgraph

Is it possible to create and render simple [indent trees](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/indent.html) in C# using [QuickGraph  library](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visualization&referringTitle=Documentation):

> QuickGraph itself **does not provide graph layout or visualization**
>   algorithms. QuickGraph provides efficient brides between the data
>   structures and existing graph layout libraries such as Graphviz, MsAgl, Glee

For an indent tree I suspect a graph is a bit of overkill. What is the reason you can't use simple object composition?